# Websockets with Quarkus 2 and MyFaces

Tags: jsf, websocket, quarkus, myfaces

After upgrading Quarkus from 1.x to 2.x it is no longer possible to use websocket with Apache MyFaces (2.3-next-M6).

The browser-console shows an error like

```
jsf.js.xhtml?ln=javax.faces:1 WebSocket connection to 'wss://some.url/javax.faces.push/some_channel?c12dbb48ce8b67f89f550dc9d32451bd' failed
```

Quarkus startup-log shows the message

```
(Quarkus Main Thread) f:websocket support enabled but cannot found websocket ServerContainer instance on current context.
```

Any ideas how to get websockets working with Quarkus2 and MyFaces?

Comment: I'd put ALL of your configuration for your app in your post. I'm sure other would be interested to see what's up